# IIS7 HTTPS 301 redirect

Tags: iis-7, http-status-code-301

I have two websites running on the same IIS7 instance - let's call them oldname.com and newname.com (the newer one is simply a rebranded version of the old one). Both sites are SSL-enabled. The certificate for oldname.com has expired. I'm trying to set up an HTTP301 'moved permanently' redirect for requests to http://oldname.com to be redirected to https://www.newname.com. That works, but the issue is that visitors to https://oldname.com get the SSL 'certficate expired' warning generated before they reach https://www.newname.com. Is there any way to overcome this without renewing the certificate for oldname.com?

(Note: visitors to http://oldname.com are redirected to https://www.newname.com perfectly, as one would expect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could buy a inexpensive SSL Certificate for oldname.com or use a 90 day trial for free. Hopefully after 90 days the oldname.com will no-longer be indexed. You will still have a problem with people using bookmarks that are for oldname.com

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping to avoid having to renew the certificate only because our email system provider has also changed and getting the SSL order confirmation email out of a mailbox on that old system is now non-trivial. Anyone else out there have an idea?

Comment: Email is not the only verification method for domain validated SSL certificates. If you can add a DNS CNAME or place a text file in your domain document root you can get a DV certificate. https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1367

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of those alternatives. I've accepted your answer.